# Deleting multiple records in one request via XML CWP

Tags: xml, filemaker

Is there a way of deleting multiple records in a single request via FileMaker Server's XML custom web publishing?

I'm looking through the fms13_cwp_xml.pdf and I see the `-delete` and `-delete.related` command references, but I don't see anything that would allow me to delete multiple records in the current table with one request.

I would like to avoid making multiple requests to delete every record individually.

I know I can write a script that will perform the find I want and delete all of the records, but that means that part of my web app's domain business logic exists separate from the app itself (i.e. not ideal).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `-script` and `-find` in a single request, so you can make a generic script to delete the current found set and use it with any `-find`.

Comment: This is my backup plan if there are no other options. I didn't want to move business logic needed for the web app into the FileMaker database, but if there's no other option I may need to :/

Comment: A generic “delete all” script is not business logic, just an utility.

Comment: True, but at least one other developer at the clients business will have full access to the FileMaker file after I deploy. I can tell him "don't alter this script" but there is still a chance that he out someone new could add to, delete, or change the script in a way that makes its purpose different.

Comment: That developer can also disrupt the processing in myriad other ways (change or remove fields, layouts, accounts, privilege sets, etc.). You cannot control all this anyway.

Comment: Very true. I'm going with the script, it's the best option available. I was just hoping to keep everything ultra clear within the web app with as much clarity as possible. Calling a script from the web app called "Delete found set" is pretty clear, but if could have called a built in command that does the same thing I would have preferred that. But yeah, a script is the best option. I'm also going to build a separate FileMaker file as a web app interface to the main FileMaker file. That will make me feel a bit safer because I can tell the client "don't change this file".

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

1. You might set up a custom relationship in FileMaker, in which the left-hand table's join field contained a global field, and the right hand table is the table you want to delete records from, and its join field is its primary key. You can then set the left-hand global field to contain a list of all the primary keys of the records you want to delete. You could then pass all the id's you'd like to delete, set the left-hand global field, and use -delete.related to delete all the records in one step.
2. (**Updated: Per Mikhail's comment below, the correct API to do this is the xDBC API, and not the XML API**). I believe (about 95% certain, but not positive) that you can use FileMaker SQL with the XML API. Assuming that's correct, you could simply issue a standard SQL DELETE/FROM/WHERE… command to delete all records in one step.

Comment: What you're describing 1 would work, though it's still moving buisness logic into the FileMaker database which I'm trying to avoid. Good idea though. I tried to look up 2 in the documentation but couldn't find it. If it existed that would be the ideal method as far as keeping the buisness logic for the web app within the web, but I can't see how to do it :/

Comment: You cannot do SQL via XML API.

Comment: Chris, to close the loop on this: in my tentative #2 suggestion above, I was thinking of the O/JDBC API, which does indeed allow execution of arbitrary SQL. If it's relatively easy for you to access this from your web app, you could then use arbitrary SQL against your FileMaker data. This would of course allow you to execute something like DELETE… FROM… WHERE to remove an arbitrary set of records in one swoop … and keep all biz logic in the appropriate layer of your web code. Here's the reference: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/14/en/fm14_odbc_jdbc_guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could create a record for the user's session based on IP or something that has cascading delete enabled. Set the related data as needed and simply delete the session record and put it back in place right after the delete. Just use caution with cascading deletes, and test thoroughly.